# Show alert box using redux observable

Tags: react-native, react-redux, redux-observable

I am using redux observable in my react native application, On my login screen I want to show a react native alert dialog box if credentials are not valid. Can i fire alert in my epic but in epic I can only return an observable, so how to achieve this using redux observable ?

- Update 01

Authentication code:

```
export const signInFailure = (payload) => {
  return {
    type: SIGN_IN_FAILURE,
    payload
  }
};


const signInSuccessActions = (payload) => {
return Observable.concat(
    Observable.of({type: SIGN_IN_SUCCESS, payload}),
    Observable.of({type: 'Navigation/NAVIGATE', routeName:          'MainTabView'})
);
 };


export const signInRequestEpic = action$ =>
action$.ofType(SIGN_IN_REQUEST)
    .mergeMap(action => AuthService.login(action.email,  action.password)
        .flatMap(payload => payload.status === 200 ?  signInSuccessActions(payload) : signInFailure(payload))
        .catch(error => Observable.of({
            type: SIGN_IN_FAILURE,
            error
        }))
    );
```

Using alert api in react native is just 1 liner

```
import {Alert} from "react-native";

 Alert.alert(
        'Invalid',
        'Email or password incorrect',
    )
```

Comment: How do you show an alert box in react-native? Can you provide the code for your Epic that you have now, that handles the auth?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. My login epic is as following:                       `export const signInRequestEpic = action$ =>
    action$.ofType(SIGN_IN_REQUEST)
        .mergeMap(action => AuthService.login(action.email, action.password)
            .flatMap(payload => payload.status === 200 ? signInSuccessActions(payload) : signInFailure(payload))
            .catch(error => Observable.of({
                type: SIGN_IN_FAILURE,
                error
            }))
        );`

Comment: How do you show an alert box in react-native? I've never used it.

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: Awesome! thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Side note: most questions are really just normal RxJS [questions in disguise](https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable/issues/224), not specific to redux-observable; which defers pretty much everything to regular RxJS. If you're able to generalize the problem to normal RxJS, without redux-observable terminology, finding the answer will often be easier as there are tons of RxJS resources as well users on StackOverflow, Gitter, etc who can help.

---

There a couple ways to do it.

### Do it inside your existing Epic

You can use the [`.do()` operator](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-do) to make side effects that do not affect the stream of actions in any way--like just showing an Alert box without any confirmation.

```
export const signInRequestEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(SIGN_IN_REQUEST)
    .mergeMap(action =>
      AuthService.login(action.email, action.password)
        .flatMap(payload => payload.status === 200
          ? signInSuccessActions(payload)
          : signInFailure(payload)
        )
        .do({
          error: ({ payload }) =>
            Alert.alert('Invalid', `Sign in failed: ${payload.message}`)
        })
        .catch(error => Observable.of({
          type: SIGN_IN_FAILURE,
          error
        }))
    );
```

You could also just do it inside the `.catch()` before you return the stream of `SIGN_IN_FAILURE`, but I personally like to separate side effects to make them stand out more. But here is that:

```
.catch(error => {
  Alert.alert('Invalid', `Sign in failed: ${error.message}`);

  return Observable.of({
    type: SIGN_IN_FAILURE,
    error
  });
})
```

### Do it inside a *new* Epic

If you'd prefer to abstract this side effect out of the `signInRequestEpic` you could create another epic which just listens for failures, and shows the alert using [`.do()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-do) and then use the `.ignoreElements()` operator to ignore the matched actions cause this epic doesn't need to ever emit anything.

```
export const signInFailureEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(SIGN_IN_FAILURE)
    .do(({ payload }) =>
      Alert.alert('Invalid', `Sign in failed: ${payload.message}`)
    )
    .ignoreElements();
```

---

Which one should you use? It depends. If you'd like for your redux store to be updated *before* the alert is shown then you'll definitely want to use a separate Epic. With a second epic, the `SIGN_IN_FAILURE` action will have already reached your reducers before `signInFailureEpic` receives it, so they'll be updated. If you did it in `signInRequestEpic` the action won't have reached the reducers yet.

It's possible to have the store update and be in the same epic, but it starts to get hairy so I'm not going to show how ;)

Comment: Waoh thanks for such a quick reply, this is exactly what I was looking for and thanks for creating such a useful library.

Comment: @ask007 You're very welcome! If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: @jayphelps Can you please provide an example where it needs to wait for the confirmation, it would be very helpful, Thanks.

Comment: @Anas sure! wanna make a new SO question? Be sure to include exactly what you mean by "wait"; i.e. is the confirmation API you're using blocking, like prompt()/confirm() are or async?

Answer (score 0):

Better way would be to set a state in the reducer for the SIGN_IN_FAILURE and also the reason. Use these in Login Screen and show an alert in componentWillReceiveProps or a custom modal error message in render method
Something like this

```
class LoginScreen{
  componentWillMount(){
    this.componentWillReceiveProps(this.props);
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    const { loginError } = nextProps.loginState;
    if(loginError){
      Alert.alert('Invalid','Email or password incorrect')
    }
  }
  render() {
    const { loginError } = this.props.loginState
    <View>
      <Modal visible={loginError}>
      </Modal>
    </View>
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    loginState: state.login,
  };
};

LoginScreen = connect(mapStateToProps)(LoginScreen);
export default LoginScreen;
```

Make sure to reset the loginError redux state once the alert dialog is closed

Comment: Thanks, I am doing it this way but was wondering if we can do it inside an epic.

Answer (score 0):

Have not used React Native, but could you do something like this? And then dispatch this action in the catch of the AuthService.login()?

```
export const toggleAlert = action$ =>
    action$.ofType(OPEN_ERROR_TOAST)
    .map(action => Alert.alert('Invalid',action.payload))
    .switchMap(alert => {
      alert.open();
      return action$
        .ofType('CLOSE_ERROR_TOAST')
        .do(_ => alert.close())
    })
```